# Remove Material Design Dialog Host Background Color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, material-design-in-xaml

I am trying to open a popup using MaterialDesigns `DialogHost` that contains a `Border` with red background an rounded corners.

[image: A dialog showing a Border with red background and rounded corners and the dialog hosts grey background visible in the corners.]

I only want the red color, not the gray background. Where does it come from? How do I remove it?

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost Panel.ZIndex="566" x:Name="mainWindowDialogHost">
        <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
            <Border Height="500" Width="200" 
                    CornerRadius="120" Background="Red">
            </Border>
        </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the background of the dialog host using the `DialogBackground` property like this.

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost Panel.ZIndex="566" x:Name="mainWindowDialogHost" DialogBackground="Red">
```

This property is available since version 4.3.0. For older versions, you have to adapt the default style.

Unfortunately, the corner radius of the `DialogHost` is hardcoded. In order to change it, you have to copy the default style (control template) and adapt it. Copy it from the MaterialDesign GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/8c1a23547b5631d832bac8fdb92388f2d0c20796/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.DialogHost.xaml) to a resource dictionary in scope. If you include it in the application resources, make sure to include it after the MaterialDesign resource dictionaries to override the default style. If this is an individual dialog host, you can of course make the style explicit by assigning an `x:Key` and referring to it in your `DialogHost` `Style` property as static or dynamic resource.

You have to change the `UniformCornerRadius` value in the `PART_PopupContentElement` element.

```
<wpf:Card x:Name="PART_PopupContentElement" 
          Margin="{TemplateBinding DialogMargin}"
          wpf:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(wpf:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth)}"
          UniformCornerRadius="120"
          Tag="{TemplateBinding DialogBackground}"
          TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
          FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False"
          Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
          Focusable="True"
          IsTabStop="False"
          IsHitTestVisible="True"
          Opacity="0"
          RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"
          Content="{TemplateBinding DialogContent}"
          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding DialogContentTemplate}"
          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding DialogContentTemplateSelector}"
          ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding DialogContentStringFormat}">
```

The resulting dialog looks like this.

[image: DialogHost with red background and 120 DIPs rounded corners.]

Comment: Thank you. I modified the template using their github code.

Comment: I've tried but this site says "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 backgrounds when you have a dialog from a DialogHost

The first is the one of the DialogHost zone itself, that can be set to transparent by setting the OverlayBackground="Transparent".

And the second one if the one of the content that is set inside the Template of the dialog host and it is not exposed. So either you rewrite the complete template of the dialog host (quite some XAML) or with code behind you find the control of the dialog content and change its background.

Exemple that make it like you want, tested with Material design 4.0.0 (I modified the last function to make it work in this case, may be it is possible to make it cleaner)

XAML

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost OverlayBackground="Transparent" Loaded="DialogHost_Loaded" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=showdialog}" CloseOnClickAway="True"  >
            <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
                <Border CornerRadius="50" Background="Red" Height="200" Width=" 200" ></Border>
            </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
    ...
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Code behind

```
private void DialogHost_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Card card = FindVisualChild<Card>((DialogHost)sender);
            if (card != null)
            {
                card.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            }
        }

        private static T FindVisualChild<T>(Visual visual) where T : Visual
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
            {
                Visual child = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);
                if (child != null)
                {
                    T correctlyTyped = child as T;
                    if (correctlyTyped != null)
                        return correctlyTyped;

                    if (child as Popup != null) // specific to this case
                    {
                        Popup popup = (Popup)child;
                        if (popup.Child != null)
                        {
                            T subChild = popup.Child as T;
                            if (subChild != null)
                                return subChild;
                        }
                       
                    }
                    T descendent = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                    if (descendent != null)
                        return descendent;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```